# Replacing subplot colorbars with one colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray, colorbar

I am trying to create a figure with 6 subplots all with the same colorbar. I am able to plot everything together, but python automatically adds a color bar to each plot. Therefore, when I attempt to create and add another colorbar that spans the length of the figure, it still has all 6 original colorbars as well as the newly created one. How can I create a colorbar that will span the length of all 6 plots/entire figure, and still delete/remove the single colorbars for each subplot?

Here's my code and an example output (the two middle plots are supposed to be empty at the moment):

```
fig, axs = plot.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=3, axwidth=5, proj='pcarree')
ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6 = axs
axs.format(suptitle=('MAM S06 Change in (m/s)'), 
       coast = True,latlim = (20,50), lonlim = (235,293), innerborders = True)
S06_mam_seas_1.plot.contourf(ax=ax1, levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_2.plot.contourf(ax=ax2, levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_3.plot.contourf(ax=ax3, levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_4.plot.contourf(ax=ax4, levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_5.plot.contourf(ax=ax5, levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_6.plot.contourf(ax=ax6, levels = levels)
ax1.set_title(str(Diff1) + ' - ' + str(BASE))
ax2.set_title(str(Diff2) + ' - ' + str(BASE))
ax3.set_title(str(Diff3) + ' - ' + str(BASE))
ax4.set_title(str(Diff4) + ' - ' + str(BASE))
ax5.set_title(str(Diff5) + ' - ' + str(BASE))
ax6.set_title(str(Diff6) + ' - ' + str(BASE))
```

Output of my images

[image: Output of my images]

Here is what happens when I attempt to create and add my own axis:
[image: incorrect solution]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, by setting one of the initial plotting lines to a variable, say *a*, we can then use the information from this plot in order to create our colorbar.

Next, ensure that every plotting line has the argument, add_colorbar = False. Now, you have turned off the color bar to all the plots and can proceed in creating your own.

Finally, we can create a color bar that will be added to the entire figure, rather than each individual plot. We can do this by referencing the first plot we made and called *a*. Now, for example, to plot the first 4 lines of code with one color bar, the code would be:

```
fig, axs = plot.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=3, 
axwidth=5, proj='pcarree')
ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6 = axs
a = S06_mam_seas_1.plot.contourf(ax=ax1,  add_colorbar = False,levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_2.plot.contourf(ax=ax2, add_colorbar = False,levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_3.plot.contourf(ax=ax3, add_colorbar = False, levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_4.plot.contourf(ax=ax4, add_colorbar = False, levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_5.plot.contourf(ax=ax5, add_colorbar = False, levels = levels)
S06_mam_seas_6.plot.contourf(ax=ax6, add_colorbar = False, levels = levels)


cbar = fig.colorbar(a,  loc="bottom", cmap = cmap, labelsize= 22, label = units, shrink = 1)
```

This figure was plotted using this technique:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me, this looks like xarray's [faceting](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#faceting) capabilities for plots are a nice option.
You would first have to concatenate your data arrays along a new dimension, which would be the time period.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

# Create a dummy representation of your data
S06_mam_seas_1 = xr.DataArray(
    name="s06_change", dims=("lat", "lon"), data=np.random.rand(100, 100)
)
S06_mam_seas_2 = xr.DataArray(
    name="s06_change", dims=("lat", "lon"), data=np.random.rand(100, 100)
)
S06_mam_seas_3 = xr.DataArray(
    name="s06_change", dims=("lat", "lon"), data=np.random.rand(100, 100)
)
S06_mam_seas_4 = xr.DataArray(
    name="s06_change", dims=("lat", "lon"), data=np.random.rand(100, 100)
)
S06_mam_seas_5 = xr.DataArray(
    name="s06_change", dims=("lat", "lon"), data=np.random.rand(100, 100)
)
S06_mam_seas_6 = xr.DataArray(
    name="s06_change", dims=("lat", "lon"), data=np.random.rand(100, 100)
)

# Concatenate the dataarrays along a new dimension
start_years = [1881, 1911, 1941, 2021, 2041, 2071]
end_years = [1910, 1940, 1970, 2050, 2070, 2100]
period = [f"{start} – {end}" for start, end in zip(start_years, end_years)]
S06_mam_seas = xr.concat(
    [
        S06_mam_seas_1,
        S06_mam_seas_2,
        S06_mam_seas_3,
        S06_mam_seas_4,
        S06_mam_seas_5,
        S06_mam_seas_6,
    ],
    dim=pd.Index(period, name="time_period"),
)
# Set some metadata
S06_mam_seas.attrs["long_name"] = "MAM S06 Change"
S06_mam_seas.attrs["units"] = "m/s"
```

Then, plotting becomes super simple:

```py
levels = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
g = S06_mam_seas.plot.contourf(col="time_period", col_wrap=2, levels=levels)
g.set_titles(template="({value}) - (1971 – 2000)")
```

I am not experienced with plotting maps, so you will need to make some adjustments to the code for setting the projection etc. But in the [xarray documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#maps), there is an example with faceting on maps.